# AutoCompleteTextView DropDown doesn't increase size on scroll

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, landscape-portrait

I have a custom `AutoCompleteTextView` in my application, it works well, but the problem is that if the number of items in the dropdown are more the list is displayed on the top of the `TextView` instead of below it.
So I fixed the dropdown height to a specific number.

But now the problem is when the user scrolls to see items on the list the height of the dropdown list doesn't increase. What am i supposed to do now?

I  have another issue when device is in the landscape mode, the default horizontal list doesn't appear it in fact still shows a shabby dropdown list.